# Log4j not archiving all rolling file

Tags: java, logging, log4j, archive, rollingfileappender

I am using Log4j for rolling and archiving old logs. My configuration is as below:

```
    log4j.appender.DAILY=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.DAILY.File=fas-pdp.log
    log4j.appender.DAILY.MaxFileSize=100KB
    log4j.appender.DAILY.MaxBackupIndex=500
    log4j.appender.DAILY.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
    log4j.appender.DAILY.rollingPolicy.activeFileName=myapp-pdp.log
    log4j.appender.DAILY.rollingPolicy.fileNamePattern=myapp-pdp.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.gz
```

I want to roll-over after 100 KB and maximum 500 back up file before log getting deleted. So when log size reaches 100 KB, log files are created as expected appending .1 and.2 in main file log. like:myapp-pdp.log.1 and myapp-pdp.log.2 etc. but at the end of day only one log file which is the latest one i.e myapp-pdp.log is getting archived as myapp- pdp.log.2014-06-17.gz. only. Backup index log files are not getting archived.